# Two relatively prime polynomials

Tags: polynomials

show that two polynomials f,g in K[x] are relatively prime if and only if 1 is in I(f,g). I(f,g) being the linear combinations of the two polynomials. I dont know how to start this since shouldnt 1 have to be in there in order for them to be relatively prime?

Comment: What is K[x]? Is it polynomials with integer coefficients?

Comment: What is K? If $K=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$,then for $f=2$ and $g=x$ the assertion is not true.

Answer (score 2):

This result is called [Bézout's identity for polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor_of_two_polynomials) and it's proof is based on [Euclidean algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor_of_two_polynomials)

Comment: For that $K[X]$ must be an Euclidean Domain. right?

Comment: Yes since  we should do an euclidean division.

Comment: So, what are the minimum conditions on K so that $K[X]$ is an ED.